# Binding a key to a command and automatically using the (interactive) default values for its interactive arguments

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, icicles

I would like <kbd>F5</kbd> to switch to the most recently used buffer. This functionality is accomplished by running `M-x` `icicle-buffer` and then hitting enter to *not* specify the buffer I want to switch to -- (the default behavior of icicle is to switch to the most recent buffer.)

I have tried editing my `.emacs` thus:

```el
(defun most-recent-buffer-please ()
  (interactive)
  (icicle-buffer " "))

(global-set-key [(f5)] 'most-recent-buffer-please)
```

but when I evaluate this lisp, and then hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, I get an error that starts with `Wrong number of arguments` followed by a lot of gibberish characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So where is `mde-most-recent-buffer-please` defined?

Comment: Ah -- I see it was a typo. I have fixed it now.

Comment: How about just plain old `previous-buffer` -- `(global-set-key [f5] 'previous-buffer)` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html  You don't need parentheses around f5 -- i.e., just the brackets are sufficient.  I am not familiar with using icicles.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but it sounds like what you want is `previous-buffer` (or perhaps `switch-to-previous-buffer`). The error message you got means that `icicle-buffer` takes no arguments and you are trying to pass it an argument, `" "`.

Comment: ok, yes.. That side-steps my original question, but that works. Thanks.

Comment: Your own example of `(global-set-key [(f5)] 'most-recent-buffer-please)` shows how to bind a key to a function call with *no arguments*, but that's not really what you're asking, so I've updated the title accordingly. In practice the answer is entirely dependent on the specific function's definition. However, if you *were* to pass one or more values intended to mean "use default behaviour", the chances are those values would each be `nil`. Conversely, a value of `" "` (a string containing single space) is unlikely to ever mean anything other than "a string containing a single space".

Answer (score 1):

A function can have mandatory and/or optional arguments, or no arguments at all.  When writing `elisp`, it is usually a good idea to find out what arguments are available for certain functions by typing `M-x describe-function RET [name of the function] RET`.  Drew (the author of Icicles) has indicated in his comment underneath the original question that the function `icicle-buffer` is not designed to be used in conjunction with any arguments -- therefore, adding `" "` causes the error message that the original poster experienced.

To switch to the previous buffer, Emacs already has a built-in function called `previous-buffer`.  Since the original poster has indicated a preference for the `f5` key, the following is an example of how to configure that keyboard shortcut so that it triggers `previous-buffer` -- brackets are sufficient and the parentheses used by the original poster around `f5` can be omitted:

```
 (global-set-key [f5] 'previous-buffer)
```